# How can I trigger a Kubernetes Scheduled Job manually?

Tags: scheduled-tasks, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I've created a [Kubernetes Scheduled Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/cron-jobs/), which runs twice a day according to its schedule. However, I would like to trigger it manually for testing purposes. How can I do this?

Answer (score 471, accepted):

The issue [#47538](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47538) that [@jdf mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46062397/2884309) is now closed and this is now possible. The original implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/5b57c2db0067c8a16681fe9ec57ace3ad0342c8f) but the syntax has changed.

With kubectl v1.10.1+ the command is:

`kubectl create job --from=cronjob/<cronjob-name> <job-name> -n <namespace-name>`

It seems to be backwardly compatible with older clusters as it worked for me on v0.8.x.

Comment: Be sure to check your version of kubectl, as of 5/10/18 the version installed via Google Cloud SDK doesn't have this command available. `gcloud components install kubectl` then https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/

Comment: It works also in Openshift, even as old as 3.11 (just replace `kubectl` with `oc`).

Comment: .. and the inverse operation is: `kubectl [oc] delete job <job-name>`

Comment: it's not working with an error `error: unknown object type *v1beta1.CronJob` 

`
> kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"22", GitVersion:"v1.22.4", GitCommit:"b695d79d4f967c403a96986f1750a35eb75e75f1", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2021-11-17T15:48:33Z", GoVersion:"go1.16.10", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
`

Comment: If you getting an error like this one --> "no kind "CronJob" is registered for version "batch/v1" in scheme "k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/scheme/scheme.go:28" <-- make sure your kubectl version is up to date (21+)

Comment: does this run the job, or just create it as a thing that can be run via another command?

Comment: its stupid that you need delete job and recreate it to trigger ‍♂️

Comment: This works but is it possible to modify the configuration? For example the cron's restart policy might be "OnFailure" but I want the manually triggered job to never restart.

Answer (score 29):

You can create a simple job based on your ScheduledJob. If you already run a ScheduledJob, there are jobs in history.

```
kubectl get jobs

NAME               DESIRED   SUCCESSFUL   AGE
hello-1477281595   1         1            11m
hello-1553106750   1         1            12m
hello-1553237822   1         1            9m
```

Export one of these jobs:

```
kubectl get job hello-1477281595 -o yaml > my_job.yaml
```

Then edit the yaml a little bit, erasing some unnecessary fields and run it manually:

```
kubectl create -f my_job.yaml
kubectl delete -f my_job.yaml
```

Comment: Just small addition about "erasing some unnecessary fields". Kubernetes is complaining about `*uid` fields and you can remove them easily by this command `sed -i '/uid:.*/d' my_job.yaml`

Comment: Assumption that there are already jobs in the history often does not hold.

Answer (score 22):

Unfortunately, none of the example syntaxes above works in Google Kubernetes Engine (GCP). Also, the GKE docs themselves are wrong.

In Kubernetes `1.10.6.gke-2`, the working syntax is:

```
kubectl create job <your-new-job-name> --from=cronjob/<name-of-deployed-cron-job> -n <target namespace>
```

Comment: awesome to troubleshoot problems with cron jobs resiliency, thanks!

Answer (score 15):

```
kubectl create job --from=cronjob/<cron-job-name> <job-name> -n <namespace>
```

you can use the  to delete job execution at any time `kubectl delete job <job-name> -n <namespace>`

if you want to see the list of corn jobs available use `kubectl get cronjobs -n <namespace>`

Answer (score 9):

EDIT - July 2018: see @pedro_sland's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50041304/4229593) as this feature has now been implemented

My original answer below will remain correct for older versions of kubectl less than v1.10.1

========================================================================

Aside from creating a new job (as the other answers have suggested), there is no current way to do this. It is a feature request in with kubernetes now that can be tracked here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/47538

Answer (score 9):

There is an option to trigger the cron job manually whithin this tab in k8s dashboard

[image: See image]

Comment: Great! This is helpful espeically for Minikube users who want to debug and play with cronjobs (like me) :)

Answer (score 6):

If you can use tools beyond `kubectl`, the [K9s CLI](https://k9scli.io/) is a wonderful tool that has, among other features, the trigger command that allow you to trigger cronjobs.

To do that, enter the K9s interface, search for your cronjobs using the command `:cronjobs`, select the one you want to trigger and type `t`.

Under the hood it probably creates a `Job` using the `CronJob` configuration, just like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50041304/3100523) suggested.

Answer (score 3):

I've created a small cmd utility for convenience to do just that and also suspend and unsuspend cronjobs.

https://github.com/iJanki/kubecron

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test the job, create a [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jobs/) config from your [Cron Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/cron-jobs/) (ScheduledJob) config and run it manually using the following command:

```
kubectl create -f ./job.yaml
```