# Kubernetes Run job using CronJob

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-cronjob

Is there a way through which I can run an existing Job using CronJob resource.
In CronJob Spec template can we apply a selector using labels. Something like this:

Job Spec: ([Link to job docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/#running-an-example-job))

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
label:
  name: pi
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: pi
        image: perl
        command: ["perl",  "-Mbignum=bpi", "-wle", "print bpi(2000)"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 4
```

Cron Spec:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: pi-cron
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      labelSelector:
        name: pi # refer to the job created above
```

I came across this. I want to try inverse of this.
[Create-Job-From-Cronjob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401795/how-can-i-trigger-a-kubernetes-scheduled-job-manually)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not do this in the way you want. `kubectl` only allows you to create jobs based on cronjob, but not vise-versa.

```
 kubectl create job NAME [--image=image --from=cronjob/name] -- [COMMAND] [args...] [flags] [options]
```

Available commands right now for kubectl create:

```
  clusterrole         Create a ClusterRole.
  clusterrolebinding  Create a ClusterRoleBinding for a particular ClusterRole
  configmap           Create a configmap from a local file, directory or literal value
  deployment          Create a deployment with the specified name.
  job                 Create a job with the specified name.
  namespace           Create a namespace with the specified name
  poddisruptionbudget Create a pod disruption budget with the specified name.
  priorityclass       Create a priorityclass with the specified name.
  quota               Create a quota with the specified name.
  role                Create a role with single rule.
  rolebinding         Create a RoleBinding for a particular Role or ClusterRole
  secret              Create a secret using specified subcommand
  service             Create a service using specified subcommand.
  serviceaccount      Create a service account with the specified name
```

Comment: Just want to note that with `kubectl`  you `cannot specify --from and command` upon create