# Create job from cronjob in kubernetes .yaml file

Tags: kubernetes, cron, yaml, jobs, kubectl

I need to execute a job create from cronjob in kubernetes.
Manualy I can run it like this:

```
kubectl create job manual-job --from=cronjob/some-cronjob
```

Though I'm not sure how to translate this to yaml.

[Probably](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) I need to put a **from:** section in the spec ,but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kubectl create job manual-job --from=cronjob/some-cronjob
```

You can use above method only to launch a job execution of a declared cronjob and whats more important(unfortunately for you) - you are able to that **only using kubectl cli**.

During research I also found my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54367455/9929015) on a similar question [Kubernetes Run job using CronJob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54366194/kubernetes-run-job-using-cronjob)
. There is also try in that example to achieve very similar thing as you trying to rich(but vise-versa. In the provided example there is a try to create cronjob bases on already existed job)..

```
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      labelSelector:
        name: pi # refer to the job created above
```

Both of your questions make sense, it would be very useful to have such an option, but, as I said in the beginning - that's currently not possible.

For test purposed - use provided command.

For regular usage - currently have no idea how to help you. Hope future releases will add this feature