# How to run kubernetes cronjob immediately

Tags: kubernetes, cron, kubernetes-cronjob

Im  very new to kubernetes ,here i tired a cronjob yaml in which the pods are created at every 1 minute.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

but the pods are created only after 1 minute.is it possible to run job immediately and after that every 1 minute ?

Comment: CronJob is backed by Job, you can just run a Job. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/50041304 and https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/

Comment: @d4nyll .im using kubectl create command .but it always started after specified minute

Comment: If it's not clear, you need to create the CronJob _as well as_ a Job derived from that CronJob.

Answer (score 1):

As already stated in the comments `CronJob` is backed by `Job`. What you can do is literally launch `Cronjob` and `Job` resources using the same spec at the same time.  You can do that conveniently using [helm chart or kustomize](https://medium.com/@alexander.hungenberg/helm-vs-kustomize-how-to-deploy-your-applications-in-2020-67f4d104da69).

Alternatively you can place both manifests in the same file or two files in the same directory and then use:

```
kubectl apply -f <file/dir>
```

With this workaround initial `Job` is started and then after some time `Cronjob`.
The downside of this solution is that first `Job` is standalone and it is not included in the Cronjob's history. Another possible side effect is that the first `Job` and first `CronJob` can run in parallel if the `Job` cannot finish its tasks fast enough. `concurrencyPolicy` does not take that `Job` into consideration.

From the documentation:

> A cron job creates a job object about once per execution time of its
> schedule. We say "about" because there are certain circumstances where
> two jobs might be created, or no job might be created. We attempt to
> make these rare, but do not completely prevent them.

So if you want to keep the task execution more strict, perhaps it may be better to use Bash wrapper script with sleep 1 between task executions or design an app that forks sub processes after specified interval, create a container image and run it as a Deployment.