# Can we spin off a kubernetes cronjob automatically and dynamically? How can we do it in AWS EKS, Azure AKS based on queues or notifications?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-sns, azure-aks, amazon-eks, kubernetes-cronjob

For my microservice based application, I am designing a component which is as follows:

1. Task that we want to execute is of periodic nature. For it, i planned to make use of the Kubernetes cron-jobs. It executes the job every 1 hour. This works perfectly fine.
2. In few scenarios, i want to execute this task on-demand (in stead of waiting for next hour window). For example, if next job time is 2:00pm, i want to execute it early, say 1:20pm.

There is a related question - [How can I trigger a Kubernetes Scheduled Job manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401795/how-can-i-trigger-a-kubernetes-scheduled-job-manually)

But I am not looking for a manual way of achieving it or explicitly calling `kubectl`
commands. Is there a way do it automatically, based on events/queues?

Our application is deployed on AWS EKS and Azure AKS. Can I integrate the k8 clusters to read onto some queues/pub-subs (ex. aws-sqs, aws-sns) and do it dynamically?

Your help would be immensely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you application is running on Kubernetes and don't want to get migrated to serverless function and keep everything inside the Kubernetes cluster you can use the Knative.

**Scale to Zero With Knative**

[Knative](https://knative.dev/docs/) is a serverless platform that is built on top of Kubernetes. It provides higher-level abstractions for common application use cases.

One key feature is its ability to run generic (micro) service-based applications as serverless with the help of built-in scale to zero support. Knative has introduced its own autoscaler, Knative Pod Autoscaler (KPA), that supports scale to zero for any service that uses non-CPU-based scaling matrics.

update your micro service to running with Knative minor change will be there and you can run it on Kubernetes.