# Trigger RUN NOW using kubectl

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

With GCP, you can click the RUN NOW button on a CronJob's page and the generated pod will be visible under the Managed Pods section on that same page. How can I do the same using the `kubectl` CLI?

I tried the command `kubectl create job ...` but it creates a completely separate Job and it's not connected to the CronJob.

Answer (score 0):

`kubectl create job --from=cronjob/${NAME_OF_EXISTING_CRONJOB} ${JOB_NAME}`

Comment: This doesn't behave the same as when you click the RUN NOW button in the GCP UI. It seems like its creating a completely new Job as opposed to GCP creating a managed pod inside the CronJob.

Comment: You can check out a similar case on [How can I trigger a Kubernetes Scheduled Job manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40401795/how-can-i-trigger-a-kubernetes-scheduled-job-manually/46062397#46062397)  for further more details .